# How to wrap text in quick documentation in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

After Ctrl+Q (Quick documentation) I could not see all text. I have to scroll horizontally to see all content. I could not make the editor to fit the window.

UPDATE:
The problem is only symbol definition, ie. the first line. The description (block text) is wrapped correctly. Actually, I don't want to resize this window as I prefer to keep it as I write in the same position for quick reference. I have to add that my monitor is quite small (15-inch) which is probably causing the problem.

[image]

Comment: If you expand that window per mouse this size will be retained the next time you open quick documentation.

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't solve my problem as I have 15-inch monitor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed method signature in the popup is not wrapped. There is a request you can vote for: [IDEA-169414](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-169414).

UPDATE: The documentation popup is reworked in 2018.1 and it should be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a way to configure IntelliJ to wrap text in these windows.

I think the quickest way to see the full line in the quick documentation window is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> again to make it a little bigger (and center it) or maximize it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd>

Keep in mind that the smallest version (the one that appears after the first <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>) can be resized by hovering the mouse cursor over its edge and dragging it. It's going to retain the same size the next time you open it.

Comment: Thanks. It seems the only unwrapped part is symbol definition, the rest is wrapped correctly.