# intellij-idea how to show all content on quick documentation popup and Permanently Fixed window size(width&height)

Tags: intellij-idea, popup, intellij-idea-2020

I already turn on “show quick documentation on mouse move” option, and when I hover over the class name, I can see the prompt/quick doc.
But the content of the document is too much, and the document does not wrap, so that I can only see half of the content on the left.
[quick doc only show half](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl05g.png)
and I hope to Permanently resize it and enable auto warp,make me not need to  scroll the scroll bar to view the left and right content every time
In fact, hovering the mouse cursor over its edge and dragging it, it's **NOT** going to retain the same size the next time you open it, i tried.
ps: [How to wrap text in quick documentation in IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48117426/how-to-wrap-text-in-quick-documentation-in-intellij)

who can give me some tips thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-238729) for the documentation containing preformatted code.

You can press the shortcut to display Quick Documentation twice to make it a tool window instead of the pop-up. Tool window should retain its size and position.